# How to bind data the inner list view in Windows Store apps

Tags: xaml, c#-4.0, windows-store-apps

Here is my code for binding data to the list view , unable to bind data to the inner list view written in windows store app.

Please check the out put in attached image.

ManiPage.xaml.cs:

[image]

```
public  class testchild
{
  public string data { get; set; }
}

 public class Test
  {
   public string id { get; set; }
   public string name { get; set; }
   public List<testchild> list { get; set; }
  }

  List<Test> listoftest = new List<Test>()
        {
            new Test()
            {
                id = "4218",
                name = "srujana",
                list = new List<testchild>()
                {
                   new testchild()
                   {
                       data = "hello"
                   }
                }
 },
  new Test()
{
id = "c7110",
name = "chandu",
list = new List<testchild>()
                {
                   new testchild()
                   {
                       data = "hello"
                   }
                }
  }
        };
        lstbx.ItemsSource = listoftest;
```

xaml:

```
 <ListView Height="300" Width="300" Name="lstbx">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding id}"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding name}"/>
                    <ListView  ItemsSource="{Binding list}">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding data}"/>
                    </ListView>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were quite close to the correct answer already, you just need to put the inner `TextBlock` in an ItemTemplate as well, similar as you did for the outer `ListView`.

```
<ListView Height="300" Width="300" Name="lstbx">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding id}"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding name}"/>
                <ListView  ItemsSource="{Binding list}">
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding data}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

This results in:

[image]